# Is this soil appropriate to plant this succulent baby?

Tags: soil, transplanting, succulents, potting-soil, aloe

I was browsing among the succulents section of this department store, and I found this offspring plant fallen apart on the floor! I took it to plant it since it was going to die there. The plants in the succlents sections weren't named, so I'm wondering if this is a real aloe vera.

I read the previously asked questions regarding aloe vera, and it was mentioned that it can be reproduced from these offsprings.

I used a small pot with the soil mentioned in the picture, but the plant was very unsteady in the pot, kept falling with smallest moves. I also read that the soil should be completely dry, so I'm drying it on the radiator at the moment.

However I wonder if this is a real aloe vera and if the soil is ok to be used with this plant?

[image: coconut soil]

[image: the succulent plant]

Comment: This does not appear to be Aloe Vera

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bamboo is right that generally you do need roots to replant an aloe vera pup, but anecdotally I know people who say they've been successful replanting a rootless pup. You've already got the pup and the soil, so I'd keep going with it. The coir is fine as a planting medium, but I disagree with the advice to dry it out. For the plant to root, it will need to be watered regularly. I would suggest using some sort of staking to keep the pup upright (bamboo skewers work well). If you happen to have rooting hormone on hand, you could dip the stem to give it a better chance. Otherwise, I think you just need to wait and see. If it does work, you'll start to see roots. If it does not, the pup will simply shrivel and die. It should be fairly obvious in a month or so if it is going to make it.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, that pup you have there, whilst it does appear to be Aloe vera, does not have any roots - usually, when you separate a pup or offset from the mother plant, you'd remove some soil from its base and cut carefully, making sure there are roots attached so the pup can survive. If it was anything but a succulent plant, you could have tried sitting it in a saucer of water to see if roots would be produced, but succulents do not respond well to this treatment, usually succumbing to fungal infection and rot.

Comment: Back in a few years and I find my own question as I was about to post a new one! I now have a few different succulent babies with roots. Is this same soil any good to plant succulents in general?

Answer (score 2):

You've nothing to lose, plant it and support it with a couple of twigs to keep it still. That way any possible new roots will not be broken.  water occasionally from below and keep the soil moist but not wet. As Michelle and Bamboo have said its not a forgone conclusion but worth a shot.