# Which soil should be used with Aloe Vera Barbadensis Miller, Stockton variety?

Tags: soil, aloe, potting-soil

[image]

The question [Is this soil appropriate to plant this succulent baby?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/22772/is-this-soil-appropriate-to-plant-this-succulent-baby) is relevant to some unknown Aloe but this question is specifically related Aloe Vera Barbadensis Miller, Stockton variety that has most nutrients, most healing power proven of all Aloes by the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvMUY6TNrR4&t=18m30s). I want to understand the usage of soils for the Aloe.

The point 31 min may be answering this, sandy soil with rocks is optimal soil for the adult Aloe? Now we need verification for this.

**Which soil should be used with Aloe Vera Barbadensis Miller?**

1. Which soil should be used for potting the new Aloe baby? Watered nutritient-rich soil? Which NPK nutrition profile in the fertiliser? Fertilization needed?
2. Which soil should be used with the adult Aloe?
3. What is the purpose of rocks in growing the Aloe? Only landscaping?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why [Aloe Vera Barbadensis Miller](https://middlepath.com.au/plant/aloes_Aloe_Vera_barbadensis-miller.php) should have different treatment compared to other [Aloe Veras](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloe_vera).

Aloe Vera is native from Africa semi-desertic regions. 
It's accustomed to dry rocky or sandy conditions, similar to what you have in your yard on the picture.

Probably sand shores aren't appropriate because of the salt, and constant high moisture level.

> 1. Which soil should be used for potting the new Aloe baby?

To have ideal soil, you should mix sand with potting soil. Use river sand instead of beach sand. If you can afford it, go for Granit grit (crushed granit). 
[ref](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Onv60-c6iEIC&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=aloe+vera+potting+soil&source=bl&ots=8eTaPgwthi&sig=Sfuzw8YfHRQVg6JFxeW6Rpjslvg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DD5jUMb6LaHj0gH__IDwDg#v=onepage&q=aloe%20vera%20potting%20soil&f=false)

Another hint is to use perlite in your potting mixture: 1/3 sand, 1/3 perlite, 1/3 potting soil. Perlite will enforce  creating perfectly aerated "desert type" soil for your aloe.

At a local gardening store, you can also ask for potting soil made for cactuses.

Avoid increasing the moisture level of the soil with compost: rather use slow release fertilizer pelets.
If you keep your  plant in the same pot for a very long time, regularly add **very dilute** liquid fertilizer.

[Ref](http://www.gardenguides.com/110493-root-aloe-vera-plant.html) for repoting the baby.

> 2. Which soil should be used with the adult Aloe?

Sandy and rocky soil should do, which you could fertilize with compost tea from time to time

> 3. What is the purpose of rocks in growing the Aloe? Only landscaping?

Sand and rocks are needed to aerate the soil. Aloe will grow [shallow roots](http://www.aloeplant.info/aloe-root-care/) that like breathing.
If soil stays too moist, lack of sun could cause disease and roots to rot. So you need good draining soil.

Comment: I disagree Jika.  Rocks and sand ARE NOT needed for aeration nor drainage.  That soil he has in his garden is obviously JUST FINE as his aloe is doing very well.  To make one's own potting soil takes an expert to understand how to sterilize, what additives to mix, sand is not one of those additives.  To purchase commercially made potting soil for cactus is the best someone can do.  Taking soil one knows nothing about and does not correctly sterilize that soil is asking for an iffy situation.  Compost tea is interesting and probably a good solution for the soil life of the garden soil.

Comment: Look, I'm just trying to answer the question. I'm not saying nothing else will help, I'm just saying sand and little rocks contribute to soil drainage.

Comment: But they don't.  Organic matter DOES increase Tilth and drainage. Sand does not.  Rounded pea gravel is better as it won't compact.  But you have to have organic matter in the soil. Adding sand, gravel, rock to improve drainage is a misconception that is tough to dispel.  In fact, adding rock to soil for pots can actually make the drainage even worse. Check out perched water tables.  I do like your compost tea idea to feed his already sandy soil, organisms, without changing the soil's indigenous structure that those aloes are very at home with and are thriving.

Answer (score 0):

Your adult or matured Aloe plants as shown are just fine planted in the the garden soil that you are using.  These are definitely Stockton's variety.  Purported to be the best for medicinal qualities. No additions necessary at all.

For your pups in pots you HAVE to use sterilized potting soil for potted plants, any potted plant. There are potting soils designed for succulents/cactus that I would probably use.

Fertilizer should be a simple NPK evenly numbered.  I'd use OSMOCOTE 14-14-14 for both potted babies as well as your mature plants.  Once or twice per year not their recommended use of every 3 months.

Sterilized potting soil is a solid rule for anything planted in a pot.  Don't try adding anything.  Some potting soils come with mycorrhizae and bacteria and THAT is just fine.  Some potting soils come with added fertilizer, water holding sponges or granules and that is NOT fine.  No rocks at the bottom of the soil above the drainage hole!  Just soil. Acclimate your baby aloes before transplanting into the garden.

You are assuming the role 'nature' when pots are in play as well in the garden.  In the garden you need to add a little decomposed organic matter to feed the micro and macro organisms in your soil.  These organisms make a 'live' soil and are necessary to help plants symbiotically to up take chemicals or fertilizer..chemicals YOU are relegated to provide that your plants need to do photosynthesis to make their own food. Wait to give the baby or potted plants fertilizer.  Allow them to root well first, then give a bit of fertilizer. There are all kinds of fertilizer formulations just be aware that mulch or compost is not an all purpose fertilizer.  Before any fertilization I would acquire a soil test of your garden soil. This will tell you what your soil is lacking or has in abundance.  I assume someone else was 'gardening' here before you became owner?  Who knows what they added to that soil.  Your garden soil looks perfect for these aloes however.  'If it ain't broke don't try fixing it'...

Your crop is beautiful. If you haven't already, I would get a soil test from my nearest Cooperative Extension Service...for cheap.  A little fertilizer is great, too much is death.  The baby aloes will adapt quickly to the garden soil as long as they are acclimated to the out doors and sun before planting.

As for rocks, in the garden soil, whatever is there is fine.  You aren't going to change that soil anytime soon.  Soil is little tiny rocks. The size differentiates with different soils; clay is the tiniest flat particles making up soil mixtures, then silt, then the largest particles are sand.  All soils are mixtures of these 3 sizes and the percentages make a soil type.  Soil types change as one goes down into the subsurface profiles. The other rocks that are in the soil or laying around are going to represent the same as the original rocks that made up your soil.

I only worry about rocks in my garden if they are bigger than my fist otherwise I leave them alone.  I am not sure what you meant by your rock question.  If the rocks were brought in it is most certainly for 'landscaping'.  They have nothing to do with your aloe except to create a 'rock garden'.  Those might not be anything like your indigenous rock and soil being brought from different quarries to sell to contractors.

Your plants are happy.  Gorgeous, happy aloe plants.  I wish I could scoop one up and take it home!  Consider your baby aloes in pots as 'starts'.  Perfect for gifts or selling at the Farmer's market. Are those flowers yellow?